# Проверка статуса и включение/выключение очередей Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, очередь

Добрый день.
Есть база данных, в Service broker которой есть несколько очередей, не находящихся в папке "System Queues" (dbo.queue/front, dbo.queue/process и dbo.queue/transmit).

[image: Очереди]

Поставлена задача - SQL-запросом проверить эти очереди на запущенность. Нашел следующую команду:

```
SELECT is_receive_enabled FROM sys.service_queues
```

но эта команда выводит статус только трех очередей из папки "System Queues", статус нужных мне очередей не выводится.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, запрос, которым можно проверить статус этих очередей.

Comment: Ваш запрос должен вернуть вам все очереди. Если какие-то очереди не возвращаются, значит у пользователя, которым исполняется этот запрос, вероятно, не хватает прав на соответствующий объект очереди.

Comment: @i-one, где назначаются права на очереди?

Comment: Права на объект могут наследоваться через членство в ролях (`ALTER ROLE ... ADD MEMBER ...`), либо выдаваться/изыматься напрямую (инструкции `GRANT`/`DENY`). В SSMS это делается в меню Security базы данных.

Comment: Посмотреть права на объект можно запросом: `select * from sys.fn_my_permissions('dbo.queue/front', 'OBJECT')`.